# Saving and retrieving Date from local storage

Tags: javascript, typescript, local-storage

This may seem like a silly question but I'm having a rather difficult time, understanding Typescript.
I have following code:

```
var date = new Date();
window.localStorage.setItem("date", date);
```

As you see, I'm generating todays date and store it via local storage.
Now I want to retrieve this value inside another function, add 7 days to it, store it again, and show the new value in an alert-box.

```
var date = window.localStorage.getItem("date");
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
window.localStorage.setItem("date", date);
alert(date);
```

When I run this code, it keeps telling me `Undefined is not a function` on the second rule of the second code-block (probably the `.getDate()` function).

Someone who knows what I might be doing wrong? I thought this simple piece of javascript would run fine in typescript without changing the code...

Comment: the date that you get from localStorage is a string

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Everything put into localStorage is stored as a string.  Your date is originally an object.  You need to convert the string back to an object after you get the value from localStorage.

```
var date = window.localStorage.getItem("date");
// Initialize the date object as a date object again here
date = new Date(date);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
```

Comment: That worked. I feel so stupid now. I thought it had something to do with the types in Typescript. Thank you very much!

Comment: This saved my bacon... KUDOS!

Answer (score 2):

You should store the timestamp in localStorage, and then retreive it, create a new Date with that timestamp, add 7 days, and then store it again:

```
var date1 = new Date();
window.localStorage.setItem("date", date1.getTime());

var date2 = new Date(Number(window.localStorage.getItem("date")));
date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 7);
window.localStorage.setItem("date", date2.getTime());
alert(date2);
```

Comment: "date.getTime" in line should be "date1.getTime", right?

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the following

```
var date = new Date();
window.localStorage.setItem("date", date);
var date1 = window.localStorage.getItem("date");
console.log(date1)
```

You will find that `date1` is a string. This is because localStorage stores all of its data as strings.

You should parse the string by creating a new Date with the returned string.

Comment: getDate returns the day of the month, and thus would not be suitable for this use case. The correct method is getTime.