# Loading Events in Ionic2_Calendar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic2-calendar

I implemented a version of the ionic2-Calender. It works very fine. When i have no events in my `eventSource` and create an Event, the event is displayed correctly.
The Problem comes when I am trying to load Events from my Storage. I am always getting this error:

> TypeError: eventStartTime.getFullYear is not a function at
> MonthViewComponent.onDataLoaded (ionic2-calendar.js:1768) at
> MonthViewComponent.ngOnChanges (ionic2-calendar.js:1614) at
> MonthViewComponent.wrapOnChangesHook_inPreviousChangesStorage

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the issue [here](https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar/issues/558), it says the startTime property of the event should be a date object.

> This indicates that the event startTime probably is not a valid Date
> object. Could you double check what's the type of startTime? If it's a
> string, you need to convert it into Date object.

I have also stumbled upon this when using web storage to load the calendar, which [gets converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629458/saving-and-retrieving-date-from-local-storage) data type.

The solution is very simple as we only need to iterate through the value from the storage and convert it to date before setting the value of the model itself.

```
var eventsFromStorage = window.localStorage.get("eventsCalendar");
var countData = eventsFromStorage.length;

for (i = 0; i < countData; i++) {
  eventsFromStorage[i].startTime = new Date(eventsFromStorage[i].startTime);
  eventsFromStorage[i].endTime = new Date(eventsFromStorage[i].endTime);
}

this.eventsModel = eventsFromStorage;
```